# how to get default panels back on ubuntu - jaunty

Tags: ubuntu-9.04

I am on jaunty.

I installed AWN Manager to make ubuntu look a little 'pretty' but I suspect that ubuntu crashes because of it.

How do I get back my default panel the way it was when I first installed jaunty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently

```
gconftool-2 –shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

in the terminal will get them back. You might need to run

```
sudo debconf gnome-panel
```

first, evidently.

[Source](http://www.saifur-rahman.com/2008/12/restoring-default-ubuntu-panel/).

Comment: great. that works. now only if I could make sense of what those lines actually mean then I wont feel retarded :)

Comment: Line 1 shuts down the configuration daemon so that it won't complain when you start ripping out branches of the configuration. Line 2 rips out a branch of your configuration, specifically the gnome panel branch. Line three quits gnome-panel, after which GNOME automatically respawns it, now with the default configuration. You might also need to remove AWN from your startup programs (or just uninstall it).