# how to enable multiple desktops in ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-9.04, xorg

Few days back I asked [How to get default panels back on Ubuntu Jaunty](https://superuser.com/questions/59702/how-to-get-default-panels-back-on-ubuntu-jaunty). However, now I noticed that my multiple desktops are… gone!

On the bottom right hand corner I see boxes but when clicked nothing happens. Is there a way to get back the default multiple 'workplaces' I used to have before messing around with AWN manager?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on you existing workspaces on your panel and select "Remove from panel"  Then right click on the panel again and select "Add to Panel..."  From the list of available items, select the very last one, "Workspace Switcher".  The properties of the switcher allow you to control the number of virtual workspaces - the number of rows and the number of columns.